# What package is responsible for webcam detection?

Tags: webcam

I am trying to report [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1264669) but i am unsure about the package to report it under. What package is responsible for the detection of the webcam and creation of /dev/video0 device?

Comment: Try with installing Guvcview. It also provides the drivers for the webcams. `sudo apt-get install guvcview`

Comment: @DuminduMahawela It says that it's unable to start and that i should reconnect the webcam (which is inbuilt). So it's the same thing as with camorama probably.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package for webcam detection:
(`Camorama Webcam Viewer`)

you can install it with this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install camorama
```

Comment: I already have it installed, and the problem is that the webcam device is not created at /dev/video0. So camorama can't find anything there.